# Showing highlighted value in combobox textfield on pressing up/down arrow keys

Tags: extjs

In extjs combobox (I'm using it as autocomplete), as you type, it shows the matching results.

Now if I press the down arrow key or the up arrow key, I want to see that highlighted value in the combobox textfield, similar to a google search.

How can this be done?
Any help is highly appreciated… Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should override the hightlight event of the boundlist.

[ExtJS - Update combobox text field value from highlighted row](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/56u)

```
var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
    data : [
        {"abbr":"AL", "name":"Alabama"},
        {"abbr":"AK", "name":"Alaska"},
        {"abbr":"AZ", "name":"Arizona"},
        {"abbr":"NY", "name": "New York"}
    ]
});

var combo = Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
    store: states,
    queryMode: 'local',
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'abbr',
    typeAhead: true,
    enableKeyEvents: true,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    // show mouseover item value in the combobox textfield
    listConfig: {
        listeners: {
            itemmouseenter: function(cmb, record, item, index, e, eOpts ) {
                // of course you should set unique value here, in this case 'abbr'
                combo.setValue(record.get('abbr'));
            }
        }
    }
});

Ext.view.BoundListKeyNav.override({
      highlightAt:function (index) {
        var boundList = this.boundList;
        var litem = boundList.all.item(index);
        if (litem) {
            litem = litem.dom;
            boundList.highlightItem(litem);
            boundList.getTargetEl().scrollChildIntoView(litem, true);
            combo.setValue(boundList.getNode(index).textContent);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks.Actually i use mvc and in my controller i listen to 2 events on combobox ,one is change and the other is specialkey.So do i need to add

Comment: Ext.view.BoundListKeyNav.override({
      highlightAt:function (index) {
        var boundList = this.boundList,
        item = boundList.all.item(index);
        if (item) {
            item = item.dom;
            boundList.highlightItem(item);
            boundList.getTargetEl().scrollChildIntoView(item, true);
            combo.setValue(boundList.getNode(index).textContent);
        }
    }
});    in one of those events?

Comment: i tried this,it works for me but i also want see that highlighted value in the combobox textfield when i move my mouse over the search results.Can both the functionalities be achieved...thanks

Comment: then, you can use `listConfig` property of the combobox. You can use all events of the `Boundlist` in the `listConfig` property. Check modified code.

Comment: actually,in my combobox,i am using a getInnerTpl method which shows both "abbr" and "name" like this: getInnerTpl: function(){ return '{abbr} - {name}'; }
now when i use the up/down arrow keys it shows me  'AL-Alabama' in the textfield and when i move the mouse over it ,it just shows me 'AL' in the textfield.I want to show the same data in the textfield if i do a mouse over or press up/down keys....Can this be done...thanks

Comment: Dear friend, sorry but all other things it's your problem. Have a good weekend.

Comment: the above code works fine in firefox,but in IE8, it gives me an error at : item = boundList.all.item(index); saying "Object doesn't support this action" and nothing happens when i use the arrow keys.

Comment: is because of the variable (item) defined in the global scope (means, if you not specify var keyword then variable available in the global scope). So, just define like : `var item = boundList.all.item(index)` And I learned now which is `item` has special meaning in IE! bullshit browser!

Comment: Thanks.I tried this out,it doesn't show me any error now in IE8 ,but when i type in the combobox,it shows me the search results and as soon as i press the DOWN/UP arrow key,the search results vanish away and the textfield remains blank.....Can you guide me achieve this in IE8....thanks

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve this in IE8? ...thanks